# Setting color in list item from set of 4 colors

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

In my app I have a list view. In each row of list item there is a textview which shows the initial character of name just like in many contact apps. I have to set background color of that textview from a predefined set of 4 colors defined in colors.xml. What I want is that the color should repeat after every 4 items in listview. For that I used the following logic

```
 color_array=activity.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.dar_list_color);

    if (count<4) {
   viewHolder.layout_color.setBackgroundColor(color_array[count]);

  }

  else
  count=0;


  count++;
```

This thing works fine but there is one problem , common problem with listview i.e. on scrolling color changes. As the count is not related to position from adapter, I can't figure out how to fix this one.

Here is the screenshot of what I have implemented
[image: Current Result]

Here is the complete Adapter code

```
public class DAR_Aadapter extends BaseAdapter  {
 int color_array[],count=0;
 Activity activity;
 ArrayList<DAR_List_Item> dar_List_Items;

 public DAR_Aadapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<DAR_List_Item> dar_List_Items) {
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

  this.activity=activity;
  this.dar_List_Items=dar_List_Items;
  color_array=activity.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.dar_list_color);

 }


 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return dar_List_Items.size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return dar_List_Items.get(position);
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return 0;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  ViewHolder viewHolder;
  if(convertView==null)
  {
   viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
   convertView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.dar_swipe_list_layout, null);

   viewHolder.clientname= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Client_name);
   viewHolder.client_initial= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.client_initial);
   viewHolder.text_contactedpaerson= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_contacted);
   viewHolder.text_contacttype= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_contact_type);
   viewHolder.text_createddate= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_Created_date);
   viewHolder.text_requestdate= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_request_date);
   viewHolder.text_productname= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_product);
//   viewHolder.text_status= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_status);


   viewHolder.contactedpaerson= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.contacted);
   viewHolder.contacttype= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_type);
   viewHolder.createddate= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.create_date);
   viewHolder.requestdate= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.request_date);
   viewHolder.productname= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.product);
//   viewHolder.status= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
   viewHolder.layout_color= (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.client_initial_layout);

   convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

  }else
  {
   viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
  }
   viewHolder.clientname.setText(dar_List_Items.get(position).getClient_name());
      String temp=viewHolder.clientname.getText().toString();
      viewHolder.client_initial.setText(""+temp.charAt(0));
   viewHolder.contactedpaerson.setText(dar_List_Items.get(position).getContacted_person());
   viewHolder.contacttype.setText(dar_List_Items.get(position).getContact_type());
   viewHolder.createddate.setText(dar_List_Items.get(position).getCreated_date());
   viewHolder.productname.setText(dar_List_Items.get(position).getproduct_name());
   viewHolder.requestdate.setText(dar_List_Items.get(position).getRequest_date());
//   viewHolder.status.setText(dar_List_Items.get(position).getStatus());

  if (count<4) {
   viewHolder.layout_color.setBackgroundColor(color_array[count]);

  }

  else
  count=0;


  count++;



   return convertView;


 }




 public static class ViewHolder
 {
  LinearLayout layout_color;
  TextView clientname,client_initial,text_contactedpaerson,contactedpaerson,text_contacttype,contacttype,text_productname,productname,text_status,status,createddate,text_createddate,text_requestdate,requestdate;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
count = position % color_array.length();
switch(count) 
{
      case 0:
      viewHolder.layout_color.setBackgroundColor(color_array[count]);
      break;

      case 1:
      case 2:
      case 3:
        //handle these cases separately
        //viewHolder.layout_color.setBackgroundColor(color_array[count]); 
        break;

}
```

it gives you the flexibility of handling each case separately. Where were you initializing `count` ?

Comment: initialising count in onCreate()

Comment: post that code please since that `count` probably won't work and won't relate to adapter's position.

Comment: but position will increase according to adapter and will be 0 in start. So how this will work?

Comment: that's the problem that count doesn't relate to adapter position and changes on scrolling

Comment: ouch, are you sure you ever update `count` ? it seems that it will always be 0, then enter the `if(count < 4)` branch, then increment itself, but your `count` never takes the Adapter's `position` into account either, thats why it's misbehaving. Please introduce something similar to the first codeline i pasted (above the switch()) and try again.

Comment: I am updating count in end. I am trying your method too